# Javascript HTTP Function

Tags: javascript, http

I have a device that connects to a wifi network and turn on some relays via calls on the browser address bar. For example this link is for the activation of the relay 2:

```
192.168.71.1/io.cgi?DOA2
```

I need to associate this calling to a button onpress event with javascript.

Is there a way to simulate a calling to this address without open a new tab?
the function must be invisible to the user.

Thanks

Comment: Where do you expect the JavaScript to come from? Is it part of some web application that already exists?

Comment: Look for [javascript fetch](https://www.google.se/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=javascript%20fetch)  or [XMLHttpRequest](https://www.google.se/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=xmlhttprequest) or as it's called: [ajax](https://www.google.se/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=javascript+ajax)

Comment: Look into AJAX, you'll be able to call that URL in the background and do any processing you require, without the user needing to know.

Comment: Is part of an MVC application. It's very simple...when the user click a button it open a relay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this could help to get you started? Note requires a modern browser.

**JS**

```
  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.commandButton');
  Array.from(buttons).forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      window.fetch('http://192.168.71.1/io.cgi?' + button.id);
    });
  });
```

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="commandButton" id="DOA1">DOA1</button>
<button type="button" class="commandButton" id="DOA2">DOA2</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/btfgLz2k/

Comment: If i try it i have this error: 

Fetch API cannot load http://192.168.1.76/io.cgi?DOA2=20. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63861' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: Seems that your router/endpoint does not support CORS. You could use JSONP instead of fetch. See jQuery JSONP for a good example http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/